# Integration of Tesseract OCR in a webpage - and more

Tags: python, html, tesseract

How to integrate tesseract OCR in a web page such that:

1. User selects the file via system dialogue box actioned by a button (input type, file).
2. The uploaded image is then subjected to Tesseract script and the output of the OCR is displayed on the webpage itself.

Comment: Use online software like ABBy

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge hidden problem to running tesseract in a webpage.

`pytesseract`, the popular tesseract wrapper for Python, calls on `subprocess` and `Popen` to run tesseract from the command line, then parses the results and returns them to you.

Spawning a subprocess from a web request (other than those directly managed by your webserver) will:

1. Crash or stall most Python web frameworks
2. Crash or stall WSGI processes
3. Create tons of zombie processes
4. Be a general pain to handle

So, my advice is to not.

Look for an OCR solution that runs in pure-Python or interfaces with Python through a statically compiled shared object.

Which OCR solution does that... I have no clue.

Comment: Will servlets help? I mean can it be done via server side programming that has a database for storing the uploaded image, getting it processed in backend with help of Tesseract JS and then returning the output?

Comment: I can't speak for Tesseract JS. Haven't used it. Just sharing my experience trying to get subprocesses to run on Flask/Django.

Comment: Actually, it looks like Tesseract JS is an emscripten port of Tesseract. Go ahead and use that over Python for sure. Fixes the subprocess issue.

Comment: @Chris Conlan Thanks.  I used to think subprocess will create a new process id and it will have zero effect on the parent process (python runtime).  Please help me understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Theoretically it *does* have zero effect on the Python runtime, but that is the problem. If you don't configure `subprocess` to handle all possible end-states (like asking for user input, timeouts, non-zero exit codes) then you will end up with zombie processes. CLI tools typically don't document or expose all possible runtime outcomes, so it is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisConlan I now understand better.  Thank you for the time.  Just for context - in my context it works because they are rudimentary unix commands that usually never fail.  Hence, I never realized the potential pitfall since all of them would have exited with success (or 0).  But now I know, in case any of them had indeed failed (a memory alloc issue for instance), that process would not have exited gracefully, and memory would be active for that process (zombie).  I get it, thank you.